# Do self signed SSL certificates cause websites to get flagged as unsafe?

Tags: ssl

I'm thinking about using a self signed cert for a staging area of my app.  However, this staging area is located on the same server as production, and I'm worried that using a self signed cert may cause the server to be flagged as malicious/suspicious.  Should I just go ahead and pay for a real cert?

Answer (score 2):

There is theoretically nothing wrong with a self-signed certificate, but browsers like Chrome will definitely raise a flag. I'd recommend getting a real certificate.